# iPhone games that continue even when you're away

Tags: iphone

Let's say, Tiny Tower. On this iPhone game, you can have shops in your tower. You can suspend or turn off the iPhone, but when you return to the game, you will be reported about the shop winnings during your time away.

There are also push notifications when a building is complete etc.

I fear I do not understand how that works, exactly. I'm not asking for the exact solution, I just need to know where to begin researching. One idea I had some time ago was like calculate the amount of seconds the user was away (current time minus the time when you left) and then calculate shop processing for every one of these seconds. But I'm not sure of that.

Comment: For me your idea sounds reasonable. For the push: You could look into `UILocalNotification`.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to calculate before you close the app.

Figure out what time it is, then calculate when in the future certain tasks will be completed. This way, you can schedule push notifications to the server ahead of time.

If you calculate after you have re-opened the app, and you can't run processes with the app closed, how will it know when to push?

Take a look at this article about push notifications to understand a little bit better how they work.

http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Game most probably does not actually process in the background (most apps are not allowed to do anything while in background). When you relaunch the game, it calculates how much time has passed, and then processes all the events that would have happened in the meantime.

Additionally, as Paul.s mentioned in comments below, as well as other people in other answers have suggested, on iOS4 you can use local push notifications scheduled before close.

Comment: In addition the push notifications are simply scheduled notifications so before the app is closed it probably registers any notifications that are likely to occur and when the app resumes it probably cancels any scheduled notifications that have not fired yet.

Answer (score 1):

For offline games you add temporal logic to your items and recalculate when game is launched. For online games you retrieve game state from the server, which is constantly recalculating for all users, even disconnected ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is either server side execution of the game or if it is a game of chance or something like Farmville where it's determined by time duration.

If you were to make a server and/or game like this then you would need to decide which route to take.

If it will be something where the user has good days and sometimes bad days then you'll need a lot more server power. however, if it's something like time based then you would be able to tell the last time they were logged in and the next time that they should be awarded. you can also take this idea and for each variable that you store, you store how long it takes to be complete and the start time. Then you would do a simple If then o see if the item is ready. The same thing can work for a number of visitors. Where you have 10 visitors per item per hour. If you have two items then each hour you will receive 20 visitors.